# How can I configure conditionUnless in embedded tomcat within spring boot?

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I am using spring boot with embedded tomcat.  I am currently configuring the access log as follows (in my application.properties file):

```
server.tomcat.accesslog.directory=log
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true
server.tomcat.accesslog.pattern=%t INFO "some pattern..."
server.tomcat.accesslog.prefix=tomcat
server.tomcat.accesslog.suffix=.log
```

which works fine.  Now, I would like to use **conditionUnless** property of AbstractAccessLogValve, but just putting **server.tomcat.accesslog.conditionUnless** doesn't work.

How would I set this?  Doing this in code is fine too but I don't know how best to do it.  Or should I be using a different method of configuring the valve?

Answer (score 0):

Well, looking at spring boot code, it seens that AccessLogValve is being customized as follows (in spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerProperties.java):

```
 831     private void customizeAccessLog(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory) {
 832       AccessLogValve valve = new AccessLogValve();
 833       valve.setPattern(this.accesslog.getPattern());
 834       valve.setDirectory(this.accesslog.getDirectory());
 835       valve.setPrefix(this.accesslog.getPrefix());
 836       valve.setSuffix(this.accesslog.getSuffix());
 837       factory.addContextValves(valve);
 838     }
```

So, conditionUnless is not supported.  I guess I will just need to replace this valve in my own initialization in code, rather than using application.properties file.